# What is the purpose of union inside structure here?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        u32 slock;
        struct __raw_tickets {
#ifdef __ARMEB__
            u16 next;
            u16 owner;
#else
            u16 owner;
            u16 next;
#endif
        } tickets;
    };                                                                                                                                  
} arch_spinlock_t;
```

Above is the code snippet from Linux kernel,What is the purpose of putting whole union inside structure, Why not simply union then?

This is the [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/spinlock_types.h#L23) to source code.

Comment: Could you please put a link to the source code?

Comment: Info about `__ARMEB__` may help divine the purpose.  Suspect some endian thing.

Comment: @haccks Link has been added for source code.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Kernel is a work-in-progress, rather than "see-how-it-should-be-done" thing.

I believe there's no true reason behind this, other than the habit to pack everything in `struct`'s on the top level. If you used to think of "everything is a `struct`", you may accidently fail by adding some new field to the actual `union`, not to the `struct`, as you expected.

Comment: Even if there is a deeper compatibility reason, having a struct at the top level to prevent inadvertent addition of fields to the union seems to be a good practice.  That may be reason enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to have several structs which were similar to each other but not identical - that had many common elements but then varied. An example might be a range of products for sale at a shop, where some of the items are sold in int units (I'll sell you one or two motorbikes, but not 1.5) and others are sold in float units (kgs of apples, for example)?

A Union allows you to define a number of different variables, of different types and sizes, in parallel - i.e. sharing the same memory - within a collection.

Used carefully, a union within a struct can be used to produce a collection that can handle a whole family of slightly varied data types, such as the motorbikes and apples.

C's unions let you define a block of memory which has two (or more) names associated with it so that - when combined with structs - you can produce a whole family of defined variable types based on a common core, but then varying in parts where appropriate.

### Edit: Adding Example

```
typedef union {
    int units;
    float kgs;
} amount ;

typedef struct {
    char selling[15];
    float unitprice;
    int unittype;
    amount howmuch;
} product;
```

Comment: "Used carefully, a union within a struct can be used to produce a collection that can handle a whole family of slightly varied data types, such as the motorbikes and apples." I am not understanding this, Same can be achieved through only union. Why union inside structure? can you give some example?

Comment: I don't see how the exemple answers the question: why wrapping the union in a struct, if the struct only contains the union ?

Comment: Example you have given is representing your point of view, you are correct, but my question is different, In the code snippet in question which is from Linux kernel, Why do we need to wrap up whole union inside structure instead we can typedef union and use it, What is the purpose of wrapper here?

Comment: It is just a design choice whether to put union inside the structure or a structure inside a union.

Comment: @Vineet1982: Choice is between **union inside structure** or **union alone**. The second is obviousely shorter, but the first is actually used.

Comment: Its the choice of developer how to use things